# Multiply dataframe column by dictionary when match

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe

```
    Brand    Value
0   A          2
1   B          5
2   C          6
3   D          1
4   E          4
5   F          6
```

and a dictionary

```
dic={C:10}
```

I want to multiply value by the dictionary value, when there is a match on brand and the key.

So the output is

```
    Brand    Value
0   A          2
1   B          5
2   C          60
3   D          1
4   E          4
5   F          6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a `map` with `fillna`:

```
df['Value'] *= df['Brand'].map(dic).fillna(1)
```

Output:

```
  Brand  Value
0     A    2.0
1     B    5.0
2     C   60.0
3     D    1.0
4     E    4.0
5     F    6.0
```

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
df['Value'] = df['Value'].mul(df['Brand'].map(dic)).fillna(df['Value'])
```

---

```
# print(df)

  Brand  Value
0     A    2.0
1     B    5.0
2     C   60.0
3     D    1.0
4     E    4.0
5     F    6.0
```